# Como fazer um type range ser preenchido de acordo com marcação?

Tags: range

Eu já vi isso em muitos sites, mas alguns usando JavaScript ou `box-shadow`, só que nenhum dos dois é funcional para o projeto (está sendo feito em Wordpress).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<div class="slidecontainer">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML Font</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     

</head>
<body>
   
 <p>R$<span id="demo"></span>  </p> 
  <input type="range" step=100 min="300" max="5000" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>

  

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
  width: 70%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 70%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #feae98;
  outline: 20px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .20s;
  transition: opacity .20s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  background-color: green;
  
 }

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #feee00;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var sliderparcelas = document.getElementById("myparcelas");
var meses = document.getElementById("parcelas");
var conta = document.getElementById("sozinho");


slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  conta.innerHTML = (this.value)/slider.value;
}
sliderparcelas.oninput = function() {
  meses.innerHTML = this.value;
  conta.innerHTML = (slider.value)/this.value;
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: imagem para ilustrar melhor o que desejo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript para aplicar um `background linear-gradient` com a porcentagem proporcional ao valor do range.

Na linha:

```
this.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, yellow 0%, yellow '+
perc +'%, #feae98 '+ perc +'%, #feae98 100%)';
```

Onde tem `#feae98` é a cor padrão do range, e o `yellow` é a cor do preenchimento à esquerda do botão de rolagem.

Veja o código com alguns comentários para melhor entendimento:

> Comentei a linha `conta.innerHTML = (this.value)/slider.value;` para
>   evitar erro no exemplo abaixo.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var meses = document.getElementById("parcelas");
var conta = document.getElementById("sozinho");


slider.oninput = function() {
   output.innerHTML = this.value;
//   conta.innerHTML = (this.value)/slider.value;
   var rMin = this.min;
   var rMax = this.max;
   var rStep = this.step;
   var prop = (rMax-rMin)/rStep; // calcula o número de steps
   var perc = 100*((this.value-rMin)/rStep)/prop; // calcula o percentual proporcional
   
   // aplica o background
   this.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, yellow 0%, yellow '+ perc +'%, #feae98 '+ perc +'%, #feae98 100%)';
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 70%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 70%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #feae98;
  outline: 20px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .20s;
  transition: opacity .20s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  background-color: green;
  
 }

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #feee00;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>R$<span id="demo"></span>  </p> 
<input type="range" step="100" min="300" max="5000" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
```